# Using a key to map to a range of values. Letter Grade to exam score example

Tags: java, hashmap

As the title suggests. I need the functionality of where the grade "A" is returned for any score between 90-100. Or in this case, whatever cutoff the user decides to set based on a curve or something. This is what I had but I can't think of a way to have it do what I want it to.

```
private HashMap<String, Double> letterGrade = new HashMap<String, Double>();

public void setgradeCutOff(String[] letterGrades, double[] cutoffs) {
        for(int i = 0; i < letterGrades.length; i++){
            letterGrade.put(letterGrades[i], cutoffs[i]);
        }

    }
public String getGrade(String studentName) {
    //Returns a student's average score for all exams
    double averageScore = getAverageExamGrade(studentName);
    for(Entry<String, Double> entry : letterGrade.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue() == averageScore){
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This only works if the averageScore is exactly one of the cutoff values. How can I modify it so that the string key maps to a range as specified by the setGradeCutOff method?

This is how I expect it to work:

```
setLetterGradesCutoffs(new String[]{"A","B","C","D","F"}, 
                   new double[] {85,70,60,50,0});

Laura. Average exam score: 87 Grade: A
Peter. Average exam score: 72 Grade: B
Miranda. Average exam score: 67 Grade: C
```

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. You need a more exact problem statement.

Comment: What part of it was unclear? I can make edits to it if need be but I thought this was adequate description of it. User specifies the cutoffs, and the grade gets determined based on that. I'll add an example of the functionality.

Comment: @SeanF Having read the question like couple of times, I still don't understand the idea. Do you want an average of grades or what? When you mean cutoff out of what? I can interpret this question with whatever I used to have as an assignment in school, but this question is not clear.

Comment: Cutoffs. In my example: 85 and above gets an A. 70 and above gets a B. And so on.

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov by just reading the question he is attempting to work out what the grade is of `averageScore` by looking it up in the map, however, maps require exact matchs on the key. He is trying to work out how to work out how to get the grade if the score doesn't match the key. So how does he get the closest key to the value to work out the grade. The `getAverageExamGrade` doesn't need to be shown because it isn't important.

Comment: @SeanF Thanks for pointing out the duplicate question. That actually helps. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a third-party library, `TreeMap` can do it, using the [`floorEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) method (Java 6+):

```
private static TreeMap<Double, String> gradeMap = new TreeMap<>();
static {
    gradeMap.put(85.0, "A");
    gradeMap.put(70.0, "B");
    gradeMap.put(60.0, "C");
    gradeMap.put(50.0, "D");
    gradeMap.put( 0.0, "F");
}
private static void printGrade(double score) {
    System.out.printf("Average exam score: %s Grade: %s%n",
                      NumberFormat.getInstance().format(score),
                      gradeMap.floorEntry(score).getValue());
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printGrade(87);
    printGrade(72);
    printGrade(67);
    printGrade(69.99);
    printGrade(70.00);
    printGrade(70.01);
}
```

*Output*

```
Average exam score: 87 Grade: A
Average exam score: 72 Grade: B
Average exam score: 67 Grade: C
Average exam score: 69.99 Grade: C
Average exam score: 70 Grade: B
Average exam score: 70.01 Grade: B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava's [`RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) to map the range of grades to a letter:

```
RangeMap<Integer, String> gradeLetter = ImmutableRangeMap.builder()
    .put(Range.closed(90, 100), "A")
    .put(Range.closed(60, 89), "B")
    // ...
    .build();

public String getGrade(String studentName) {
    int averageScore = getAverageExamGrade(studentName);
    return gradeLetter.get(averageScore);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work for me. My only concern is I might have to iterate through the double[] cutoffs array to retrieve the values that determine the cutoff. The performance would take a hit with a loop nested in there wouldn't it?

Comment: I think the answer should explain why HashMap doesn't work and why you need to use another type of map.

Comment: You can setup the map in ``setgradeCutOff``. Anyway, don't worry about looping over an array of 5 items.